# Failed: argument is not a function. Are you looking for `mapTo()`? (Karma-jasmine issue with rxjs map - shorthand - get method)

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use: `map(this.service.method)` 
instead of: `map((data) => this.service.method(data))`

But Karma tells me that: 
`` Failed: argument is not a function. Are you looking for `mapTo()`? `` 
and `mapTo` is not what I want to use there.

Service method which I am trying to use:

```
get method() {
  return (data) => { ... }
}
```

Comment: Try `map(this.service.method())` i.e., with paranethesis

Comment: Adding parentheses shouldn't work, `method` is a getter.

Comment: Using paranethesis expect that method would take argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Base on your comment, I don't think that the problem is in the method itself. If the problem raises only in tests, then it seems that the `this.service` has some other value than the actual service (but not `undefined` because the error would be "*Cannot read property `method` of undefined*.")

---

## Old imprecise answer

I'm afraid you did not provide full code of the service method. I sense there might be a condition inside and when you instantiate the `Observable`, the `this.service.method` getter returns `null` or `undefined`. The reason is the synchronous nature when creating the operator - the getter that returns the function get's called at the moment when the `map(this.service.method)` is called - that is immediately. Only the function provided to `map` as the parameter will be called asynchronously when the observable fires.

If I'm right, then the only way you can make this work is the way you already mentioned.

```
map((data) => this.service.method(data))
```

Comment: This is how it looks originaly:
``get mapDatabaseDataToColumnConfiguration() {
        return (settings: SettingIO[]): GroupedConfigurationIO => {
            return Object.keys(settings).reduce((result: GroupedConfigurationIO, key: string) => {
                result[key] = settings[key].settingsValue;

                return result;
            }, {});
        };
    }``
<br> It works in real time, only karma unit test dont feel it.
Maybe I should mock it, ect. ?

Comment: @KamilSocha91 Well you have no conditional in the getter. So my answer is not correct. Maybe the problem is, that the `service` is `undefined` in the test.